# Subtract gravity from acceleration data given quaternions

Tags: python, math, accelerometer, quaternions

I am trying to subtract gravity from acceleration data. I have the quaternion values in w, x, y, z form. This is my code:

```
# acc - accelerometer data
# g - gravity vector g = (0, 0, 9.81)
# q - orientation quaternion
# The approach is to rotate gravity vector to the current orientation and subtract it from acc.
def subtract_gravity(acc, g, q):

    # rotate gravity to the current orientation q, by performing q * g * q_conjugate
    g_rotated = rotate(g, q)

    # subtract rotated g from acc
    return np.subtract(acc, g_rotated)


# For the rotation, we need to perform qgq_conjuagte
def rotate(g, q):
    # Convert gravity vector into quaternion
    q_g = (0.0,) + g

    # rotate gravity to the current orientation q, by performing q * g * q_conjugate
    return q_mult(q_mult(q, q_g), q_conjugate(q))[1:]


# Normalize quaternion - the norm should be 1
def normalize(q, tolerance=0.00001):
    mag2 = sum(n * n for n in q)
    if abs(mag2 - 1.0) > tolerance:
        mag = sqrt(mag2)
        q = tuple(n / mag for n in q)
    return q


def q_mult(q1, q2):
    w1, x1, y1, z1 = q1
    w2, x2, y2, z2 = q2
    w = w1 * w2 - x1 * x2 - y1 * y2 - z1 * z2
    x = w1 * x2 + x1 * w2 + y1 * z2 - z1 * y2
    y = w1 * y2 + y1 * w2 + z1 * x2 - x1 * z2
    z = w1 * z2 + z1 * w2 + x1 * y2 - y1 * x2
    return w, x, y, z


def q_conjugate(q):
    w, x, y, z = q
    return (w, -x, -y, -z)

a = [9.1, -3.7, -0.03]
b = [0.12, 0.79, 0.56, 0.21]
acc = np.array(a)
q = np.array(b)
g = (0, 0, 9.81)
output = subtract_gravity(acc, g, q)
```

However, the output I am getting seems incorrect. I am keeping the IMU such that the gravity is predominantly affecting the X-axis and so gravity subtraction should just result in near zero x-axis, but the above code outputs [4.48 -4.25  8.61]. Any ideas on why this is happening - are there bugs in my logic?

Comment: I think this is more of a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Start by testing your code for a _known_ orientation of your IMU. Suppose your IMU X-axis is aligned with the vertical direction. What would the quaternions for this orientation be? What does your code do when you plug these quaternions in? Then try when the IMU X-axis is inclined at 45 degrees to the vertical. Then try 90deg.

Comment: For those not familiar with IMUs, can you explain what is measured and why and how this is a Quaternion?

Comment: Where is this quaternion coming from? When you look at g_rotated it is [4.5734    0.4473   -8.6250], which doesn't map into the x-axis.